# how to connect local SQL database from UWP application that can run in Raspberry PI3 device?

Tags: database, uwp, raspberry-pi3

I developed UWP application and deployed this application in one of my IOT device. But I want to connect to local SQL database from UWP application that can run in the IOT device.

For that I created WCF web service project to connect to local database. But my application run In IoT device and database available in my local machine.

Can you please tell me how to connect local SQL database from UWP application that can run in Raspberry PI3 device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update we have added support for .NET Standard 2.0 to UWP. With this you can now use SqlClient APIs to enable this scenario.

For this scenario to work, you need the following configuration: - Visual Studio 2017 Update 4 (or later) - Min version in your UWP project 16299 (=Fall Creators Update) - NETCore version 6.0.1 (or later)

Here is a sample app: https://github.com/StefanWickDev/IgniteDemos/tree/master/NorthwindDemo

Here is the session at Microsoft Ignite 2017 where we demo'ed it: https://myignite.microsoft.com/videos/53541

Comment: I tried with this link https://blog.pieeatingninjas.be/2017/09/02/using-sqlclient-in-uwp/. I deployed my application into Raspberry PI3, but I faced the issue at this line “connection.Open()” like "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)"

Comment: Does it work from your desktop PC? Do you have TCP/IP protocol enables on the SQL server?

Comment: I can't deploy UWP application in to my local machine because my OS build version is old one. Right now I used Azure SQL database instead of local SQL database.

Comment: when ever I installed Windows 10 Fall Creators Update in my desktop pc then my UWP application works fine in desktop pc. but the same application deployed in Raspberry PI 3 device it gives the same error like earlier I mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: Now I resolved the above error. I connected Raspberry PI3 device with separate LAN cable and Desktop PC connected with separate LAN but those are coming from same network. But earlier I connected Raspberry PI 3 device to my desktop pc directly with LAN cable. That’s why my Raspberry PI3 device will not recognize the Azure SQL database.

Answer (score 0):

The is no way to connect to a sql server database directly from a UWP app.  You need to create a web service to connect to the sql server and pass the info to the UWP app.  You can use databases like SQLite with a uwp app.  To use the sqlite database with a uwp app you can use the entity framework core or sqlite-net to get data to and from it

Comment: With the upcoming Fall Creators Update for Windows 10 we are adding the ability to connect directly to a SQL server database from your UWP app, using the standard .NET APIs (System.Data.SqlClient etc.). I will publish a sample a shortly.

Comment: @StefanWickMSFT, I think Fall Creators update for windows 10 now available to developers : https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/windows-developer-day?utm_campaign=windevdaycu&utm_source=autopilot&utm_medium=email&utm_content=sdkrelease can you please post respective sample with SQLClient for connecting the SQL database directly from UWP application.